# How to share ubuntu partitions on Windows Linux Subsystem?

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I have enabled the linux subsytem on my Windows 10 and installed Ubuntu and Kali.
Now I want to be able to share files and folders between Windows and these installations. How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the subsystem your drive C: is mounted on `/mnt/c/`

So you could copy files to `/mnt/c/temp/` in Linux subsystem and copy them from Windows Explorer from C:\temp\